# SQL request returns wrong id and wrong results

Tags: sql, join

Im building a form where i get all the questions from my database and where i also get the answers my user submitted ( submitted by ajax ) without submitting all the form and where i also get the reason my user submitted if he answered "no".

So im working with this request:

```
SELECT q.ID, q.Question, ra.Answer, cq.Name, rnc.Reason 
FROM Questions q 
    LEFT JOIN CategoriesQuestions cq ON q.Category = cq.Category 
    LEFT JOIN ResultatsAutoevaluations ra ON q.ID = ra.Question 
    LEFT JOIN RaisonsNonConformites rnc ON q.ID = rnc.Question_ID
WHERE q.Active = true 
AND ra.User_ID = :user 
AND ra.Evaluation_Number = :evalNumber
ORDER BY q.ID ASC
```

table Questions

```
ID  int Incrément automatique   
User_ID int 
DateAndHour datetime [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP]    
Question    varchar(255)    
Category    int 
Active  bit(1) [b'1']
```

table CategoriesQuestions

```
Category    int Incrément automatique   
Name    varchar(255)
```

table ResultatsAutoevaluations

```
ID  int Incrément automatique   
Evaluation_Number   int 
Question    int 
Answer  varchar(255) NULL   
User_ID int
```

table RaisonsNonConformites

```
ID  int Incrément automatique   
User    int 
Question_ID int 
Reason  tinytext    
Eval_Number int
```

To be simple, all i want is getting all the questions, then joining all the categories the questions are related, then joining all the answers of the questions already submitted and then joining the reasons of the questions for this form and for this user.

Also i already tried to add a WHERE clause in the sql to get the reason of the id of the actual form but then the request only return me the question where there is already a reason submitted...

https://ibb.co/M6jLVC0

Here is a screenshot of what i get while trying all queries ( including mine ) posted here.
**I colored some of the wrong ID's in red:**
The questions all have a unique id. And because some questions does have multiple id, the rest of the ids are also wrong too. every other id is off too ...
**The reason result colored in green:**
is the only good result in the column "reason" i should get in return. The other lines should be set as "null"...

I also just noticed now that the column "answer" don't returns me the answers for the right evaluation...

Comment: You might want to consider adding a [minimal, reproducible example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) and reading [tips for a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question).

Comment: The ra conditions in the WHERE clause make LEFT JOIN's return INNER JOIN result. Move to ON if you want true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: Every question can have multiple answers and multiple reasons in your data model. If a question has 2 answers and 3 reasons, then you get 2 x 3 = 6 result rows, because you join every reason with every answer for a question.

Comment: If you `select * from raisonsnonconformites where question_id = 40`, you get three rows, because there are three reasons for question 40, don't you? Why do you expect to only see one of the three reasons in your results?

Comment: To be clear : each answer is identified with the id of the user who submitted it and the id of the form and the id of the question the answer is related. A question can't have multiple answers for the same form. I don't know why im struggling so hard with this. On the paper it's just selecting everything related to the id of the form and the user but i can't get this to work :( Also yes, doing the select you talked about gives me 3 rows And that's the point of what im trying to do, i just want everything to the user and the form related. Nothing else :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to restrict the reasons to the user (and maybe the evaluation number, too).

```
SELECT q.ID, q.Question, ra.Answer, cq.Name, rnc.Reason 
FROM Questions q 
LEFT JOIN CategoriesQuestions cq ON q.Category = cq.Category 
LEFT JOIN ResultatsAutoevaluations ra ON ra.Question = q.ID  
                                     AND ra.User_ID = :user 
                                     AND ra.Evaluation_Number = :evalNumber
LEFT JOIN RaisonsNonConformites rnc ON rnc.Question_ID = q.ID
                                   AND rnc.User_ID = :user 
                                   AND rnc.Eval_Number = :evalNumber
WHERE q.Active = true 
ORDER BY q.ID;
```

This gets you all questions. If you only want questions the user answered, make this an inner join. Or if you only want questions the user gave a reason for, make that an inner join. If you want to show all questions the user answered *or* gave a reason for, keep the outer joins and add `and ra.id is not null or rnc.id is not null` to the where clause.

Comment: Wow you are a real savior, sir ! Looks good now :) I'll do some more tests and mark your post as the answer ! And yes, the solution was simple... But i didn't think about it... Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

The conditions in your WHERE clause are causing your LEFT JOINs to be treated as an inner join because the values are null when the left joined table doesn't have a corresponding row.  For example, ResutatsAutoevaluation, if it doesn't exist for this question, ra.User_ID and ra.Evaluation_Number will be NULL.  Move these conditions to the JOIN clause as follows:

```
SELECT q.ID, q.Question, ra.Answer, cq.Name, rnc.Reason 
FROM Questions q 
    LEFT JOIN CategoriesQuestions cq ON q.Category = cq.Category
        AND q.Active = true
    LEFT JOIN ResultatsAutoevaluations ra ON q.ID = ra.Question
        AND ra.User_ID = :user 
        AND ra.Evaluation_Number = :evalNumber
    LEFT JOIN RaisonsNonConformites rnc ON q.ID = rnc.Question_ID
ORDER BY q.ID ASC
```

Comment: Returns me the exact same results

Comment: You might want to add some sample data and desired output to your question to help explain the issue you're facing.  The suggestion I gave here apparently didn't address your "main" problem, but it is generally true and important, so just file that away

Comment: @The-Evil-Fox: That is weird. Eric mistakenly moved `q.Active = true` from the `WHERE` clause to an `ON` clause. This means you get now all questions, not only the active ones. Are all questions in your table active? And Eric is also right about the failing outer joins. His query gets you questions that don't have answers and reasons. If you are getting the same result with your original query, this means there are no questions without answers and reasons in your tables.

Comment: For the moment they are.

Answer (score 0):

Without sample data it's very difficult to understand but this might work:

```
UPDATE wp_posts 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
set wp_posts='' 
WHERE wp_posts.id not in (
select wp_posts.id from wp_posts 
inner join wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
inner join wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.term_id  =2365
```